# Is two-way horizontal inheritance possible?

Tags: java, inheritance

I am a high schooler who only has about 8 months of coding experience so dumb down your answers please.

I am coding a game for my class and I know, as should everyone who codes, that inheritance only goes down the chain, not up.

My question is a tad long but starts with this: Is two-way horizontal inheritance possible? Let me explain with an image:
[image: Possiblities]
Now that you see my picture, and what I mean by two-way horizontal inheritance, I now ask has anyone in the wide world created java code that makes the link shown by the red arrow possible?

When answering: I now about chaining ex. A extends JPanel, B extends A, therefore B extends JPanel, so don't tell me to chain anything. I am simply asking if there is any code from Oracle that is in development to make the bridge shown by the red arrow, or if there are any people out there who have code that can create the aforementioned bridge.

Comment: My hunch is that you want a relationship like you mention, where Subclass 1 extends JPanel and Subclass 2 extends Subclass 1.  What are you trying to do, this may let us answer your question better

Comment: Not sure what your red arrow could possibly deliver that subclass1 -> subclass2 -> JPanel cannot. Can you name something that you hope to accomplish but cannot without tvat link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is no - Java is single inheritance, so a class can not extend multiple classes. This is generally an indication that you should rethink your design. Without knowing specifics, it's hard to tell, but if Subclass1 and Subclass2 are similar, is there an abstract class you could create that extends JPanel, and then Subclass1 and Subclass2 could each extend that abstract class?

Comment: Don't forget that Interfaces can help for this situation as well.

Comment: @JeffStory I was just curious to know if anyone, e.g. Oracle or some clever software genius has created code that can allow for horizontal inheritance. If this existed, I would be so happy because it would allow all the classes(dealer, and players) in my blackjack game to communicate allowing me code to work 100%

Comment: There are languages that support multiple inheritance, Java just isn't one of them. It's not about clever way to do things, it's a language choice. I would suggest you rethink your design if you think you need horizontal inheritance like this and make sure you're actually trying to create "is-a" relationships with inheritance or if (as others have pointed out) composing together objects (via interfaces) is more appropriate.

Comment: @user3519829 Using inheritance for this is unworkable/unnecessary. You can communicate fine with composition. E.g. have a class called Game where all the logic is implemented, and which holds the references to the instances of the Player/Dealer classes.

Answer (score 1):

No, because it's unnecessary. [Using composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), you can always get the equivalent of any class structure you want.