# What is horizontal inheritance?

Tags: java, inheritance

Not once I heard about the so called horizontal inheritance, I tried googling it but didn't find anything that would clarify it for me. What is the fundamental difference between the two types of inheritance?

Comment: Where did you hear it mentioned? And what is the second type you are speaking of?

Comment: Do you mean *horizontal reuse*?

Comment: "Horizontal inheritance" is not a concept that is directly relevant to Java. It's a database thing. See, e.g., https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13189_01/kodo/docs316/ref_guide_mapping_classmapping.html

Comment: May be check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23232570/is-two-way-horizontal-inheritance-possible

Comment: "Horizontal Inheritance" is not a thing, and it doesn't really make sense, because the inheritance relationship is what defines the vertical direction.  It sounds like another word for "delegation" that someone just made up.  Sometimes people or companies make up jargon that only applies to their specific context, and then talk about it out in the world as if it's a thing everyone knows already.  Note that @Sneftel refers to (horizontal (inheritance mapping)) not ((horizontal inheritance) mapping)

Comment: Well the second type is the vertical inheritance. @MattTimmermans Exactly! It did not make sense to me and it does not. Even though it is occasionally mentioned on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13189_01/kodo/docs316/ref_guide_mapping_classmapping.html) and comments above, there is no such thing as "horizontal inheritance".

What there is ... is "horizontal inheritance mapping".  And that actually means is horizontal mapping of inheritance to tables.  As distinct from flat or vertical mapping of inheritance to tables.  In other words the "horizontal" versus "vertical" versus "flat" is about the scheme for mapping ... not the nature of inheritance itself.

Answer (score 1):

I think this term is used in php, it is supposed to resolve somehow the problem of multiple inheritance through the use of "trait <-> use" keywords
take a look :
"Traits use a form of inheritance that is known as horizontal inheritance in which the code from the trait is included in the classes in which it is used. It is pretty much like using ‘require’or ‘include’ in the classes to include code from the outside, albeit not hackish." 
From : "The essentials of Object Oriented PHP: Learn, practice, and apply" by Joseph Harosh